# When does the get method hits the database?

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to learn difference between get and load.Example of my code is this---

```
public class StudentTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SessionFactory sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();

        Student student=new Student();
        student.setName("Rajat");
        student.setDate(new Date());
        student.setCompany("Yash");

        session.persist(student);

        Transaction t1=session.beginTransaction();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        student.setName("Prashant");

        Student getStudent1=(Student)session.get(Student.class, 1);
        System.out.println("-----------get------------------");
        System.out.println(getStudent1);


        session.close();
        sessionfactory.close();
    }
```

if get hits the database why?? the output is

```
Student [id=1, name=Prashant, company=Yash, date=Thu Apr 20 17:22:20 IST 2017]
```

while in database it is saving name as Rajat.

Answer (score 0):

Get loads the object directly from the database , so when executing get you will see select sql on the logs.

Load provides a proxy for the requested set, whenever you actually use the requested set the sql will be performed the set will be fetched

Comment: i tried load instead of get then also it return name=Prashant and in database it is Rajat. How do i get actual data from database in above example??

Comment: yeah it will return the same data, before the System.out.println(getStudent1) line, if you are using load then your variable is holding a proxing not a reference to the object it self, once the print is executed it will fetch the data from the database and use it, either way you are getting actual data

Comment: How its actual data??Since the database table have name=Rajat and the output I am getting is Prashant.

Comment: thats a different case which has nothing to do with load/get, what happens here is that after you committed your transaction your object stays in the persistence context, when requesting object first its looked up in the persistance context, so since the object in the persistence context is changed it will be the one to be fetched